# manipulate input file and create a new file using awk

Tags: awk

Input

```
1473697,5342715,256,0.3

1473697,7028427,256,0.1

1473697,5342716,256,0.3

1473697,5342715,257,0.3

1473697,7028427,257,0.1

1473610,7028427,256,0.1

1473610,5342715,256,0.3

1473610,7028422,256,0.1
```

Output

```
1473697,256,5342715 0.3 7028427 0.1 5342716 0.3

1473697,257,5342715 0.3 7028427 0.1

1473610,256,7028427 0.1 5342715 0.3 7028422 0.1
```

`OFS` and `FS` is `=` ,
is there a way to search unique lines base on column 1 and 3
then print the line with the details from column 2 and 4

Comment: please better the format of the question and explain on top what you want to do and what the problem is

Comment: A duck and a giraffe are walking along the beach.  Is there a way to search a dog?

Comment: Is the data already in a particular order? Can we expect the keys to be all grouped together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took awhile to figure out what you want, but I think you're looking for:

```
awk '!a[$1 $3] {a[$1 $3] = $1","$3","} 
    {a[$1 $3] = a[$1 $3] " " $2 " " $4}
    END {for(i in a) print a[i]}' FS=, input-file
```

or

```
awk '{a[$1","$3] = a[$1","$3] " " $2 " " $4}
    END {for(i in a) print i","a[i]}' FS=, input-file
```

There are many variations on the theme.

Comment: thank you very much William.. I just need to update the solution you provided as the output was a bit different.